# no Apache 2.4 win32 binary?

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server

I am wondering, is it just me or everybody, that [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi) doesn't have the Win32 binary on their site? If it thus, then where can I download the latest version **Apache 2.4.3**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a nice little notice at the bottom of their download page saying to download the win32 binaries from mirrors. A quick google search for "apache 2.4 windows" gives results:

http://www.apachelounge.com/download/

Comment: Mirrors have nothing to do with it: there are no Win32 binaries on mirrors as well.